# Angular unit test formbuilder service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have written a service to check whether the form value has changed or not so that i can update the markAsPrisitine like below

```
export class FormStateService implements OnDestroy{
  subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  isFormPrisitine(formName: FormGroup) {
    console.log('form', formName);
    const defaultValue = formName.value;
    const observer = formName.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(200))
      .subscribe(value => {
        if (JSON.stringify(defaultValue) === JSON.stringify(value)) {
          return formName.markAsPristine();
        }
      });
    this.subscription.add(observer);
  }

}
```

For the above service i have written a spec like below but the issue with the spec is how to check whether the formValue changes or not.can anyone tell me how to mock the formvalue changes

```
describe('Service: FormState', () => {
  let service: FormStateService;
  let formGroupMock: FormGroup;
  let formBuilderMock: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [FormStateService]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(FormStateService);
    formGroupMock = new FormGroup({
      field : new FormControl()
    });
    formBuilderMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('FormBuilder', ['group']);
    formBuilderMock.group.and.returnValue(formGroupMock);
  });

  it('should instantiate the service', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('it should make', () => {
    formGroupMock.patchValue({
      field: {
        name: 'test1',
        age: '11'
      }
    });
    spyOn(service, 'isFormPrisitine').and.callThrough();
    service.isFormPrisitine(formGroupMock);

    expect(service.isFormPrisitine).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```